# SharpSVN update to specific revision c#

Tags: c#, sharpsvn, svn-update

I'm iterating over the svn revisions from `sourceRevision` to `targetRevision`.
In each iteration, I wish to update my repository to the revision I'm current in.

Something like:

```
SvnClient svnClient = new SvnClient();

svnClient.Update ("C:\Svn", 26592);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track. The revision number can be passed in via the `SvnUpdateArgs` object:

```
SvnUpdateResult result;
SvnUpdateArgs args = new SvnUpdateArgs();

// If args.Revision is not set, it defaults to fetch the HEAD revision.
if (revision > 0)
{
    args.Revision = revision;
}

// Perform the update
using (SvnClient client = GetClient())
{
    client.Update(localPath, args, out result);
}
```